Is it possible to input an EOF into the VSCode terminal without having to start a newline?
Normally, in VSCode, you need to press <Enter> <Ctrl-Z> <Enter> to create an EOF character. However, I'd like to write an EOF without having to create a newline. Is this possible?
I've tried just pressing <Ctrl+Z>, but it doesn't give me an EOF - neither does <Ctrl+Z+Enter>. Therefore, when I run, for instance, a C program, it detects an extra character before the EOF that I did not intend to input.

In VSCode your terminal can run different shells. So which one are you using?

Just the regular terminal Linux-esque shell that pops up when you run a program. It’s just called “Terminal”

If it is "Linux-esque", then Ctrl+Z is suspending the process and Ctrl+D is sending EOF.

Well, most Linux commands work on it but Ctrl+D doesn’t actually send EOF, I’ve seen on other posts that it’s Enter + Ctrl-Z + Enter? Sorry, I’m not super familiar with the shells that VSCode makes.

I don't think it is possible in the Windows console. A <CTRL+Z> will only be treated as an EOF if it occurs at the beginning of a line or immediately after another <CTRL+Z>, so the program will read an end of line sequence or an ASCII  (<CTRL+Z>) character before it sees the EOF.

An interesting detail with the WIndows console (possibly a bug) is that if you continue reading after EOF, the next character is discarded, although if that character was a  that will be discarded anyway in text mode, the  that follows it can still be read. 123<CTRL+Z><CTRL+Z><Enter> will be read as 123<SUB>, EOF, <LF> in both text mode and binary mode (<CR> discarded). 123<CTRL+Z><CTRL+Z>456<Enter> will be read as 123<SUB>, EOF, 56<LF> in text mode or as 123<SUB>, EOF, 56<CR><LF> in binary mode (4 discarded).
